# issue with link to external js file

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I have a problem with the `document.ready` function. I put my external `.js` link at the bottom but trigger function on the top and I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: scrollWin is not defined

Is there any possibility to add the link to `.js` file in the bottom, or do I have to put it in the `<head>`?

```
<head>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="scrollWin()">Click me to scroll</button>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script> 
</body>
```

The JavaScript file:

```
// custom.js file
$(document).ready(function() {

    function scrollWin() {
        window.scrollTo(300, 500);
    }

});
```

Comment: define function outside on document.ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define function outside on document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});

 function scrollWin() {
     window.scrollTo(300, 500);
 }
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  scrollWin = function ()
  {
     window.scrollTo(300, 500);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much .. but i can ask you why it cant be inside document.ready function ?

Comment: you can't call foo() from the inline script immediately after ready() because the ready() code hasn't yet run

Comment: but there one method by which you call define function indise docuemnt.ready..i have updated above